# Text value in javascript's code

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a little problem with my code.
I would like put a String in my function Confirm() in javascript but it doesn't work.

```
myData.setValue(i, 9, '<a href="'+scriptDelete+'" onclick="return confirm();" > Delete </a>');
```

It's my code and I want put a String in confirm("hello")    but, i don't find the solution.

Thx

Comment: JavaScript embedded in HTML embedded in JavaScript? Eugh. Do yourself a favour and work with DOM methods instead of smashing strings together to make HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
myData.setValue(i, 9, '<a href="'+scriptDelete+'" onclick="return confirm(\'hello\');" > Delete </a>');
```

You have to escape `'` with `\'`.

Comment: @Hanny94 If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it with the tick on the left (15 minuts has to left after adding question).